# Modal View Controller with storyboards in iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am new to storyboards, but in my new app I have created 2 view controllers. On the storyboard, I have connected them with a modal segue. I would like to launch the modal view controller based on a certain condition in the "viewDidLoad" method of the first view controller. What is the correct way to do this so that I could change the transition in InterfaceBuilder if I wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Specify an identifier for the segue in Interface Builder.
2. Invoke `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifierHere" sender:self];` in `viewDidLoad` as appropriate.

See [Triggering a Segue Programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW4) in the *View Controller Programming Guide.*